# How to get EclipseLink 2.6.0-m3 working with Jersey 1.18.3

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

when using jersey moxy

```xml
    <!--  Jersey moxy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-moxy</artifactId> 
        <version>1.18.3</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

together with eclipse link 2.6.0-M3

```xml
    <!-- Eclipse Link persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.2-RC1</version> -->
        <!-- <version>2.5.1-RC3</version> -->
        <!-- <version>2.5.1</version> -->
        <!-- <version>2.5.2-M1</version> -->
        <!-- <version>2.5.2</version> -->
        <version>2.6.0-M3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                <groupId>commonj.sdo</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

i  get

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.<init>(JAXBMarshaller.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$JAXBContextState.createMarshaller(JAXBContext.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.createMarshaller(JAXBContext.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.createMarshaller(JAXBContext.java:1)
```

i tried to work-around the issue by changing the order in my pom.xml and that
works in some of my projects. In a nested environment where some projects depend on another the issue showed up again.

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg08372.html
suggest that a dependeny might be missing so I added:

```xml
   <!--  
    http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg08372.html
    http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final 
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

right where the eclipselink dependency shows up. This seems also to help.

**Is this really a bug? What would be a "proper" way to solve this issue?**

Unfortunately there is no option for me to upgrade Jersey to 2.x since there are too many incompatibilities and (as I hear) bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to solve this issue is to add javax.validation:validation-api dependency.

Bean validation is new feature in EclipseLink 2.6.0 as stated in Design Doc https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=241506

The result is, that there is now required dependency.

I have filed new enhancement request against EclipseLink to make this dependency optional.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460330